# SQLite Query: match any integer

Tags: sqlite

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT num1,num2,num3,num4 from num_cols WHERE num1=1 AND num2=2 AND num3=3 AND num4=4;
```

I would like to reuse this query in contexts in which I may not wish to match every number exactly, so if I could do something like this:

```
SELECT num1,num2,num3,num4 from num_cols WHERE num1=1 AND num2=2 AND num3=* AND num4=4;
```

where `*` would match any num3. Is there a character or function like `*` in sqlite3 which will match any value?

Is there one for integers? Is there one for strings?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just leave num3 off the select list? Wouldn't that 'match' any integer? Or, if num3 could be null say

```
num3 is not null
```

Comment: I would really like to use the same query with a full set of parameters, having one query would be convenient for me. Alternatively I would have to write 4! (factorial) queries to cover every combination (not fun, especially as I have a couple cases like this)

Comment: it appears I can, I'll test this with my case I think it will work